# Image is not showing up on my website (django)

Tags: python, django

I am new to django. I wanted to upload an image but it doesn't show up on website. Instead, it shows a broken image icon. I tried to use load static block but it still doesn't work.

My html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <title>Website</title>
</head>
<body>
   <h1>Hello</h1>
   {% load static %}
   <img src="{% static 'webdev/static/webdev/images/images.jpg' %}">
</body>
```

urls.py file:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from homepage import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home_page, name='home'),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

views.py file:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse


def home_page(request, *args, **kwargs):
    return render(request, 'home.html', {})
```

file tree:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/EYxNI.png

Comment: You need to add the `static` views to the `urlpatterns`: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-during-development

Comment: Can you share a filetree that contains the root of the project and the file you want to display?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jtZ8t.png

Comment: can you share the settings related to `STATIC` (so with `STATIC` in the name)?

Comment: STATIC_URL = 'static/'

Comment: this is the only setting with STATIC in it's name

Comment: then you should move the `static/` directory one level up (such that it is a subdirectory of the `webdevelopment/` root directory), and set `STATIC_ROOT` to `'static/'`.

Comment: still not working, but i get this error in inspect(f12)

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: KajusRudokas: can you update the filetree, and show the settings you used? Can you please be a bit more *responsive*...

Comment: STATIC_URL = 'static/'
STATIC_ROOT = 'static/' these are all STATIC settings I used

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EYxNI.png (updated filetree)

Comment: can you add `STATICFILES_DIR = ['C:/Users/User/PycharmProjects/webdevelopment/static']` to the settings?

Comment: Okay I added it.

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation on *Serving static files during development*](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-during-development) explains how to set up static files. You need to add the views that serve the static files to the `urlpatterns`:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path

from homepage import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home_page, name='home'),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

This will serve static files when `DEBUG` is set to `True`. In case of *production* (`DEBUG = False`), Django does *not* serve static files. Then you should configure the webserver (nginx/apache/…) to serve the static and media files, or work with a CDN.

Furthermore the path is:

```
<img src="{% static 'webdev/images/images.jpg' %}">
```

Comment: still not working

Comment: @KajusRudokas: the path was also invalid. See edit.